# How to get Publication Title using Tom.net

Tags: 2013, tom.net

I'm adding the publication title in config file and from there i want to call that title in the resolved item, but in the below code I'm able to read the Pub ID but it will change across the environment for that reason i want to get the publication title/name.

```
    public class ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver : IResolver
        {
     private const string ConfigFile= "ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver.config";
            /// <summary>
            /// Website Structure Publication TCMURI in config file
            /// </summary>
     **private const string WebsiteStructurePublicationFieldName = "IgnorePublications";
            private readonly List<TcmUri> _websiteStructurePublicationUri;**
            public ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver()
            {
       _websiteStructurePublicationUri=GetWebsiteStructurePublicationUri();
            }        /// For Publish and UnPublish, remove all items from the website structure Publication from the list.
            /// Website structure Publication URI is read from the config file.
            /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="resolvedItems">List of items that are currently to be rendered and published (added by previous resolvers in the chain)</param>
   public void Resolve(IdentifiableObject item, ResolveInstruction instruction, PublishContext context, Tridion.Collections.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems)
            {
            List<ResolvedItem> itemsToRemove = new List<ResolvedItem>();
                StringBuilder infoMessage = new StringBuilder();
                infoMessage.AppendLine(string.Format("Removed the following items from a {0} Transaction to {1}:", instruction.Purpose,          context.PublicationTarget.Title));
                // check for items from the list of publications to ignore (these do not need to be published or unpublished) 
                foreach (ResolvedItem resolvedItem in resolvedItems)
                {
                    // mark all items from IgnorePublications for removal
      **var publicationUri = resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri();    var publicationTitle = resolvedItem.Session.GetObject(publicationUri).Title;**
           if (WebsiteStructurePublicationFieldName.Contains(publicationTitle))
                    {
                        itemsToRemove.Add(resolvedItem);
                    }

                }          
  foreach (ResolvedItem itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
                {
                    infoMessage.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2})", itemToRemove.Item.Id.ItemType, itemToRemove.Item.Title, itemToRemove.Item.Id));
                    resolvedItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
                }
                if (itemsToRemove.Count > 0)
                {
                    // log info mesage about which items have been removed (optionally this can be logged as a warning to stand out in the logfile)
                    Logger.Write(infoMessage.ToString(), "ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver", LoggingCategory.General, TraceEventType.Warning);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but try:

```
var publicationUri = resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri();
var publicationTitle = resolvedItem.Session.GetObject(publicationUri).Title;
```

UPDATE:

As in:

```
// _websiteStructurePublicationUri is now _websiteStructurePublicationTitles
// (a List<String>) as you want it to be environment agnostic
foreach (ResolvedItem resolvedItem in resolvedItems)
{
    var publicationUri = resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri();
    var publicationTitle = resolvedItem.Session.GetObject(publicationUri).Title;
    // mark all items from IgnorePublications for removal
    if (_websiteStructurePublicationTitles.Contains(publicationTitle))
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(resolvedItem);
    }
    // remove all items that we need to discard
    foreach (ResolvedItem itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
    {
        infoMessage.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2})", itemToRemove.Item.Id.ItemType, itemToRemove.Item.Title, itemToRemove.Item.Id));
        resolvedItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }
    if (itemsToRemove.Count > 0)
    {
        // log info mesage about which items have been removed (optionally this can be logged as a warning to stand out in the logfile)
        Logger.Write(infoMessage.ToString(), "ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver", LoggingCategory.General, TraceEventType.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to pass the publicationUri as in the publicaitontitle. In my code at the top i have declared variable    private readonly List<TcmUri> _websiteStructurePublicationUri; if i pass _websiteStructurePublicationUri in the var publicationTitle = resolvedItem.Session.GetObject(_websiteStructurePublicationUri ).Title; throwing me overload error

Comment: Use resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri() instead of _websiteStructurePublicationUri. Transform List<TcmUri> to List<string> and compare you list with publication titles not TcmUris

Comment: Why are you trying to pass _websiteStructurePublicationUri in? Look at both lines... I'm showing you how to get the publication title from the resolved item, which you can then match with your config file

Comment: @DavidForster I have updated my code above in the question can you go through and pls let me know the changes i have done is correct or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: private const string ConfigFile = "ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver.config"; private const string WebsiteStructurePublicationFieldName = "IgnorePublications"; private readonly List<TcmUri> _websiteStructurePublicationUri;public ChildPublicationsOnlyResolver()
 { foreach (ResolvedItem resolvedItem in resolvedItems) { var publicationUri = resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri(); var publicationTitle = resolvedItem.Session.GetObject(publicationUri).Title;
    if (WebsiteStructurePublicationFieldName.Contains(publicationTitle))
       { itemsToRemove.Add(resolvedItem);}

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Publication publication = (Publication)engine.GetObject(resolvedItem.Item.Id.GetContextRepositoryUri());
string publicationTitle = publication.Title;
```

Comment: is Engine available in a custom resolver?

Comment: You got me there David :)

Comment: @DavidForster we want to check from each resolved items the publication name is present in the config or not . whatever the above code you have mentioned it will work for this scenario also right